# Javascript concurrency and asynchronous operations

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, concurrency

I am trying to understand how javascript handle concurrency with this script:

```
let buffer = [], total = [], count = 0;

const a = setInterval(() => {
  buffer.push(count);
  count++;
}, 1);

const b = setInterval(async () => {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
  total = [...total, ...buffer];
  buffer = [];
}, 1);

setTimeout(() => {
  clearInterval(a);
  clearInterval(b);
  console.log(total.length + " elements");
  for (let i = 0; i < total.length; i++) {
    if (i !== total[i]) {
      console.log("Error on " + i);
    }
  }
}, 10000);
```

Example of output:

```
8227 tries
Done !
```

From what I understand, intervals A and B will run in a single thread, and while interval B is waiting for the promise to resolve, interval A will keep running.
However interval A will never be able to run after the promise is resolved and B's execution is resumed, so I shall never see an `Error on x`, is that correct ?

I tried to replace the interval like below and get errors, so I think I am correct, but I'd like to be 100% sure about this.

```
const b = setInterval(async () => {
  total = [...total, ...buffer];
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
  buffer = [];
}, 1);
```

Comment: _"and while interval B is waiting for the promise to resolve"_ - That's not how `setInterval()` works. It doesn't care about the fact that the callback is `async` and `await`s a `Promise`. It will execute the callback every `1` (not really) millisecond and create a new `Promise` that will resolve after 500ms

Comment: _"However interval A will never be able to run after the promise is resolved and B's execution is resumed"_ - Why?

Comment: In this context the execution is single threaded, so the callbacks can never be executed at the same time

Comment: [Concurrency model and the event loop - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) - Your script without the array stuff and less aggressive timers: https://jsfiddle.net/3ru0t6z5/

Comment: Thanks @Andreas ! This link answered a lot of question